# Usage of Pause and Play buttons in html5

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="a">&#65;</div></td>
        <td><div class="n">&#78;</div></td>
        <td><div id="t">&#84;</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### **script**

```
function animateat() {
  document.getElementById('audioTag1').play();
      document.getElementById('audioTag1').play();
      $("#a").animate(
            { "top": "300px", "color": "white" },
             2000, function () {
                $("#t").animate({  "top": "300px", "color": "white"      
},
                 2000,function () {
                $("#t").animate(
          { "left": "760px" },1000);
}
);
}
```

### **html**

```
<body onload="animatepaapa();">
<audio id="audioTag1" src="paara.wav" preload="auto">
<code>audio</code>
```

I am developing a scene using *HTML5, CSS and JS* as shown above, in which I want to use the play, pause and as well as the replay button.

If there is a way please suggest me.

Comment: Developing a scene? Could you please elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do? Some code would be really helpful

Comment: what you've done so far?

Comment: I am taking a word using unicodes and by using the letters of that word I am trying to develope some other words by moving them down and pairing with some other letter. The formation of the entire scene with audio is giving a scene.

Comment: I would highly recommend you do some research on your own to get started (Google is a powerful search engine), and help us help you. Show us what you've tried, some code samples, and we'll help you from there.

Comment: @Danbopes I have done searching and couldnt find a solution for my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*script*/
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#stop").click(function() {
$("#a").stop(true,false);
$("#t").stop(true,false);
}); 
$("#start").click(function() {
 animateat();
}); 
});

/*html*/
<input type="button" id="start" value="start"/>
                            <input type="button" id="stop" value="stop"/>
```

It has worked for me and fulfilled my requirement.
   Thank You.